# Arquillian Graphene browser screenshooter: Cannot use Drone with Qualifier

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I'm using the `Arquillian 1.1.6.Final` for testing the `JSF` by using the `Arquillian Drone 2.0.0.Alpha3`, `Arquillian Graphene 2.1.0.Alpha2` and `Arquillian Browser Screenshooter 2.1.0.Alpha2`. It works great and give me a `screen shot` as expected.

There is some trouble when I used `Arquillian Drone` with `org.jboss.arquillian.drone.api.annotation.Qualifier` as

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no context available for qualifier org.jboss.arquillian.drone.api.annotation.Default. 
Available contexts are [interface test.com.scc.aspg.demo.arq.simple.MyExtraBrowser].
at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.context.GrapheneContextImpl$LazyContext.getContext(GrapheneContextImpl.java:302)
at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.context.GrapheneContextImpl$LazyContext$1.getTarget(GrapheneContextImpl.java:311)
at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneProxyHandler.getTarget(GrapheneProxyHandler.java:149)
at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:118)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy336.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at org.arquillian.extension.recorder.screenshooter.browser.impl.BrowserScreenshooter.getTakingScreenshotsBrowser(BrowserScreenshooter.java:158)
```

My Code is as the following: -

```java
import org.jboss.arquillian.drone.api.annotation.Qualifier;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Qualifier
public @interface MyExtraBrowser {

}

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DroneTest {

    @Drone
    @MyExtraBrowser //<---This works without Arquillian Browser Screenshooter
    private WebDriver browser;

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void ensureIndexPage() {
        try{
            browser.get("http://www.google.com")
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help to advise further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug [ARQGRA-467](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQGRA-467) fixed in 2.1.0.Alpha2 that was supposed to fix it.

See https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-recorder/issues/10 for details.

Maybe you should add a comment there.

Comment: After upgrade the `arquillian-browser-screenshooter` to version `2.1.0.Alpha3`. It works fine. Thank you very much for your advise.